# How to add css classes into react component in storybook?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, storybook

I cant see my stylings in the react component inside a storybook.

My main.js file:-

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-actions', '@storybook/addon-links'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

No CSS classes are loaded:--
[Screenshot for no classes name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrybz.png)

For information, I am using SCSS for styling.